# How to search for a Timestamp value in Google Sheets

Tags: search, google-sheets, timestamp, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to search a range for a specific value as shown in the sheet.
I'm using VLOOKUP but for some reason, it returns an incorrect value.
this is the formula:
`=VLOOKUP(A50,A54:C56, 3)`

[image: Here is the table I am struggling with]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4th parameter is missing. use this instead:

```
=VLOOKUP(A50, A54:C56, 3, 0)
```